# What is the meanings of "hiticks" and "loticks" in assembly langauage?

Tags: variables, assembly, assemblies, cpu-registers

I'm trying to understand a code that was written in **assembly language** Can anyone please tell me the meaning of "hiticks" and "loticks" in the code below? Are they registers or variables? I checked over the n=internet but could not get any examples.

```
 mov dx,1AH
    mov ax,[loticks]
    sub dx,ax
    mov [hiticks],dx
    mov ax,[hiticks]
    jmp end
hiticks dw 0H
loticks dw 10H
    end
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Neither. `lotick` on the bottom line followed by `dw` is definition of symbol/label, i.e. "name" for memory address (labels are like bookmarks into memory). That `dw` will emit two bytes of machine code (forming word value `10h`, so the two bytes will be 16 and 0) and the label `loticks` points at the first byte. Then in the other parts of source like `mov ax,[loticks]` - that's memory operand, using `loticks` as memory address => targetting those two bytes, so `ax` after the `mov` will contain that value `16` (unless the memory content there was modified meanwhile to something else).

Comment: And I wouldn't call them "variables" as in the answer below, because in assembly they lack any of the high level language features, for example you can do (on 80386+ CPUs) `mov eax,[hiticks]` which will load four consecutive bytes of memory, i.e. both "hiticks" and "loticks" "variables" at the same time, concatenating those 16+16 bits into 32 bit `100000h`. The assembler or CPU will not block you to do this, if you wish, so thinking about it rather as memory and bookmarks into it is safer, than thinking about it as "variables" and expecting some kind of type checking. That's up to programmer.

Comment: I still don't get it. Does this mean that both loticks and hiticks have a value of 0?

Comment: No, they are memory addresses. Exact value depends on where they get linked (and/or relocated by OS loader)... for example if this was inside DOS COM file, which is loaded from offset 100h, then the code ahead is 11h bytes long, so `hiticks = 111h` and `loticks = 113h`. So `mov ax,[loticks]` is then `mov ax,[113h]` and if `ds` points to the correct segment of memory where that code resides, the `ax` will load value `10h` from memory (initialized at that address by `dw 10h`).

Comment: maybe try to read this https://homepage.cs.uri.edu/faculty/wolfe/book/Readings/Reading04.htm (I did it just quick glance, didn't see anything completely wrong/horrible, although I was not completely amazed either... there's a bit short part about memory addressing at the very end of the page, but it may be enough to get the idea how these labels in asm source are placeholders for actual memory addresses)

Answer (score 0):

Those are variable declarations.

`hiticks dw 0H` declares a double-word (dw), that is a 4 bytes long variable, named `hiticks` and set its value to 0.

`loticks dw 10H`declares a double-word named `loticks` and set its value to 0x10.

---

Some more information: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_variables.htm

Comment: DW stands for **D**efine **W**ord, not double-word. Using Intel taxonomy, both are indeed 16-bit words.

Comment: I still don't get it. Does this mean that both  loticks and hiticks have a value of 0?